One FormControl becomes invalid after submit
I have a reactive form initialized by the OnInit interface, which takes the values from the store patching the form with them. When I submit the form, I dispatch an action bound to an effect that simply saves the settings inside the localStorage.
The dispatching of the action triggers again the ngOnInit method but for some reasons, one of the fields becomes invalid. This doesn't occur if I remove the dispatching of the action in the submit method.
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm()
    this.store.select(selectSettings).subscribe({
      next: (settings) => {
        console.log('Getting settings from store', settings)
        this.isLoading = false
        this.settingsForm.patchValue(settings)
      },
      error: () => {
        // ...
      }
    })
  }

Among the form fields there's one defined in initForm as the following:
  initForm() {
    const URL_REGEXP = /(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi

    this.settingsForm = this.fb.group({
      // other fields
      bgjob: this.fb.group({
        sqs_queue: this.fb.group({
          url: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(URL_REGEXP)]),
          profile: new FormControl('')
        })
    })
  }

The issue occurs for sqs_queue control: as soon as I submit the form, it becomes invalid, even if the content seems to be the same
  onSubmit() {
      this.settingsService
        .saveSettings(this.settingsForm.value)
        .subscribe({
          next: () => {
            // ...
            this.store.dispatch(set({settings: this.settingsForm.value}));
          },
          error: (err) => {
           // ...
          }
        });
  }

The form itself is specified as the following:
 <form [formGroup]="settingsForm" (ngSubmit)="settingsForm.valid && onSubmit()">
 <!-- other stuff -->
        <mat-form-field formGroupName="sqs_queue" floatLabel="auto">
          <mat-label>SQS Queue URL</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder=""
            formControlName="url"
          >
        </mat-form-field>
 <!-- other stuff -->
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="!settingsForm.valid || isLoading"
      >
        Submit
      </button>

And the related effect is the following:
  saveSettings = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(set),
      tap((action) => {
        localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(action.settings));
      })
    ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );


Why is this occurring?
Is it possible to avoid triggering again ngOnInit after the submit even if I dispatch an action?

Edit
To avoid the reloading of the component after the action's dispatch, I unsubscribe from the subscription obtained by the store selector inside ngOnInit before submitting the form:
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm()
    this.storeSub = this.store.select(selectSettings).subscribe({
    ...
   }

 onSubmit() {
      // Avoid to reload the component after dispatching the action
      this.storeSub.unsubscribe()
      this.settingsService
      ...
 }

If there's something better to do, please advice, thanks

Are you sure that is invalid?, see that you have disabled the button also when loading=true. NOTE: The submit not trigger any ngOnInit, ngOnInit is trigger when the component comes to the "scene"(when router or if it's under a *ngIf)

Yes, it's marked as invalid (I noticed it by the dedicated CSS first). The store is updated and it seems this causes the reloading of the component. Apart from the fact that this is unnecessary, the validation gets somehow corrupted

ngOnInit is not retriggered etc, it looks like your "select" observable triggers new value. You should not unsubscribe from it for sure in onSubmit, you might better need to add .pipe(first()) for your .select to execute only once to prefill the form. So the issue is that your store is somehow being changed when submitting that it triggers an update to your select. I'd set the breakpoint on line this.initForm() to confirm ngOnInit is not retriggered on submit and also inside next: ... and from next check the callstack to understand what causes the state change

Thanks @DanyloGudz you're right, using pipe(first()) solves all the issues, thanks
